# Constraint optimisation: condition that only applies to second item selected onward?

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I have a constraint optimisation question (OR-tools specifically). I'm trying to minimise the cost of sending packages by different shipping providers. Each of them has some dimension constraints, but some shipping providers have the option of sending more than one package, and they have a **cheaper rate for 2nd items onward.**

How can I incorporate a constraint (or objective?) of charging **one price for the first item selected, and a different price for all additional items?** Bonus points if there's any way of making it tiered - e.g. **one price for the first item selected, another price for item 2 through item 5 and a third price for items 6+.**

Here's some of my code for reference - let me know if anything looks off/ how you would improve:

def cost_optimisation():

```
# Instantiate solver
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

# Get data
data = get_model_data()

### VARIABLES ###

# whether a courier can ship a parcel (T or F depending on whether the courier is eligible to ship the parcel)
parcel_by_courier = {}
for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']:
    for courier_num in data['courier_range']:
        parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] = solver.BoolVar(f"parcel_{parcel_num}_courier_{courier_num}")

# the total number of parcels shipped by a courier
all_courier_sums = {}
for courier_num in data['courier_range']:
    all_courier_sums[courier_num] = solver.IntVar(0, len(data['parcel_range']), f"{data['courier_names'][courier_num]}_total_parcels_shipped")

print('Number of variables =', solver.NumVariables(), '\n')

### CONSTRAINTS ###

# add constraint that all parcels have to be shipped
for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']:
    solver.Add(sum(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] for courier_num in data['courier_range']) == 1)

# add weight & dimension constraints
for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']:
    for courier_num in data['courier_range']:
        solver.Add(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] * data['parcel_weights'][parcel_num] <= parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] * data['courier_weights'][courier_num])
        solver.Add(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] * data['parcel_largest_dimensions'][parcel_num] <= parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] * data['courier_largest_dimensions'][courier_num])

# add a constraint that couriers can only ship >1 parcel IF "further_item_allowed" = True
for courier_num in data['courier_range']:
    solver.Add(sum(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']) <= 1 if data['courier_further_item_allowed'][courier_num] is False else sum(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']) >= 0)

print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints(), '\n')

### OBJECTIVE ###

# Calculate costs for the objective and run the solver

total_base_item_cost = []

for courier_num in data['courier_range']:
    for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']:
        if all_courier_sums[courier_num] >= 2:
            if ???:
                total_base_item_cost.append(data['courier_first_item_pence'][courier_num] * parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num])
            else:
                total_base_item_cost.append(data['courier_further_item_pence'][courier_num] * parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num])
        else:
            total_base_item_cost.append(data['courier_first_item_pence'][courier_num] * parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num])

total_cost = sum(total_base_item_cost)

solver.Minimize(total_cost)
status = solver.Solve()
```

(obviously the `???` are where I started losing it)

Comment: Just for confirmation-- you've tested and your code is working for the case of constant cost per package?

Comment: Just do not write if in a sum(). move the conditions out. It will be a first step.

Comment: You'll first also need to add a constraint to make ``all_courier_sums[courier_num]`` equal to the sum of ``parcel_by_courier[i, courier_num]`` for i in parcel_range, for each courier. As coded, the variables ``all_courier_sums`` are not constrained.

Comment: Yes, tested that it works for constant cost per package. RE: Laurent's comment, I'm a little unclear about which sum() to move away from

Comment: ``solver.Add(sum(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']) <= 1 if data['courier_further_item_allowed'][courier_num] is False else sum(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']) >= 0)`` might not be doing what you expect. You want to enforce ``all_courier_sums[courier_num] <=1`` if the courier can only carry one package. You don't need the second part, the sum will always be >= 0, it doesn't have to be constrained.  Laurent suggests moving the if outside and only add a constraint for couriers with the limitation.

Comment: Ahh right, thank you both - made those two amendments and code is looking much neater (and the `all_courier_sums` variable is actually working!) - any tips on having different rates for first item v. other items? My current thinking is that I can have my 'base rate' for a package be the additional item cost and just add a fixed cost of the difference between the first item and the cheaper 2nd items onwards. E.g. if first item is £3 and all items onward are £1. I can make the general cost £1 and have a fixed cost of £2 added to the total cost for each provider

Answer (score 0):

A construction testing the values of an `IntVar` like in an if statement

```
if all_courier_sums[courier_num] >= 2:
```

will not work. The value of an IntVar is not defined outside the solver, it's only a container, a variable whose value is to be determined during the solution.

First, add a constraint to enforce that `all_courier_sums[courier_num]` is equal to the sum of the `parcel_by_courier` for that courier

```
for courier_num in data['courier_range']:
    solver.Add(Sum(parcel_by_courier[parcel_num, courier_num] for parcel_num in data['parcel_range']) == all_courier_sums[courier_num])
```

Define a variable `courier_cost[courier_num]` for each courier.

Then you can create a formula for the cost for each courier like this:

```
for courier_num in data['courier_range']:
    p1 = data['courier_first_item_pence'][courier_num]
    p2 = data['courier_further_item_pence'][courier_num]
    c1 = solver.IntVar(0, len(data['parcel_range']) * max_cost_per_parcel)
    solver.Add(c1 == (p1 * all_courier_sums[courier_num]))
    qty2 = solver.IntVar(0, len(data['parcel_range']))
    solver.AddMaxEquality(qty2, [0, (all_courier_sums[courier_num] - 1)])
    c2 = solver.IntVar(0, len(data['parcel_range']) * max_cost_per_parcel)
    solver.Add(c2 == ((p2 - p1) * qty2)
    solver.Add(courier_cost[courier_num] == c1 + c2)
```

Caveat: I didn't actually check this syntax. If it doesn't work, break it down into separate variables for the individual terms and build up the expressions term by term. The solver will create these extra variables internally anyway even if you don't do it explicitly.

If there are more intermediate price levels you can extend the principle here for 4th, 6th or whatever price steps there are.

To get the total cost, you have to make the variable `total_cost` be an `IntVar`.

Constrain it to be equal to the sum of `courier_cost[courier_num]` for `courier_num` in the range of couriers.

Then you can use total_cost as the objective.